Why coredump when using std::sort + lambda applied on a vector of values with almost the same order?
I abstract a simple example as following:
struct SItem
{
      int value = 0;
   // int key = 0;

      SItem(int val = 0)
      {
          value = val;
      }
};

#include <algorithm>
main()
{
      std::vector<SItem> items;
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
      {
          items.push_back(SItem(i));  // OK
          // items.push_back(SItem());   // doredump
          // items.push_back(SItem(99)); // coredump
      }

      auto comp = [](const SItem& a, const SItem& b)
      {
          return a.value <= b.value;
      };
      std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), comp);
}

In normal occasion, we won't try to sort items with almost the same value, but the predicator function (lambda) may treat very different items as with the same order. I've tried several times, and found that, there must be at least 4 different order-value in the vector to avoid coredump when call std::sort.
I want an explanation, and avoid such strange error in future.

Your comparator doesn't obey strict weak ordering.

Which, btw, is a nice example of how making a wrong assumption can lead to a big waste of time. With your comparison function simply not up to specs, all your experiments leading to "I must have 4 different elements" along with the assumption that std::sort is broken in general are completely pointless. Also, in general, assume that the library is working and your code is not -- you'll rarely  be able to find bugs in the library, especially with super-trivial use cases.

" may treat very different items as with the same order" -- std::sort does that already. If comp(a,b) is false then a does not have to be shuffled to come before b and if comp(b,a) is false then b does not have to be shuffled to come before a. That is what happens with <. With your comparator, if a==b then a must be shuffled to come before b and b must be shuffled to come before a

Don't use <= use < or you will not get strict (weak) ordering

Why will std::sort crash if the comparison function is not as operator <?

Your comp is invalid for std::sort. The requirements are:

For all a, comp(a, a) == false.
If comp(a, b) == true then comp(b, a) == false.
if comp(a, b) == true and comp(b, c) == true then comp(a, c) == true.

Because you use <=, neither the first nor second point are met. You need to use <.
Passing an invalid parameter to a function in std means your program has undefined behaviour. For some inputs it crashes, for others it doesn't.
